# php use 1 sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make my queries short?

I have the same query multiple times on my page on different sections.

Here's the code to see what I mean:

```
//sql for dropdown contact type 
$sql_getContactType1 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_phone_contact_type');
$sql_getContactType2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_phone_contact_type');
$sql_getContactType3 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_phone_contact_type');
```

Output in dropdown:

```
<select name="contact_type1" class="form-control">
<?php 
    while($row = $sql_getContactType1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[d_name] . '</option>';
    }
?>  
</select>
<select name="contact_type2" class="form-control">
<?php 
    while($row = $sql_getContactType2->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[d_name] . '</option>';
    }
?>
<select name="contact_type3" class="form-control">
<?php 
    while($row = $sql_getContactType3->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[d_name] . '</option>';
    }
?>  
</select>
```

How can I achieve it in just one query statement on my output?

Comment: Have you tried using 1 statement and repeat the output 3 times?

Comment: this link will help you http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 2):

Do the query once, put the results in an array, and then use that array in each `<select>`.

```
<?php
$sql_getContactType = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM tb_phone_contact_type');
$contact_types = array();
while ($row = $sql_getContactType->fetch_assoc()) {
    $contact_types[] = $row;
}
?>
<select name="contact_type1" class="form-control">
<?php 
    foreach($contact_types as $row)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[d_name] . '</option>';
    }
?>  
</select>
<select name="contact_type2" class="form-control">
<?php 
    foreach($contact_types as $row)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[d_name] . '</option>';
    }
?>
<select name="contact_type3" class="form-control">
<?php 
    foreach($contact_types as $row)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[d_name] . '</option>';
    }
?>  
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I appeciate all the help. Cheers!

Comment: @RJJMMJ So why not upvote and/or accept those answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why using 3 select? u can use one they do same job. 
For selects you must use foreach.

Answer (score 0):

First, get all data in a single query. Then you can add `if` inside your loop to determine the `contact type` to show. This example code may help you:

```
$contacts = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_phone_contact_type')->fetch_assoc();

<select name="contact_type1" class="form-control">
<?php 
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        // fit this code by the `type` you want to show
        if ($contact['type'] === 'CONTACT_TYPE_1') {
            echo '<option value="'.$contact['id'].'">'.$contact['d_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>  
</select>

<select name="contact_type2" class="form-control">
<?php 
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        // fit this code by the `type` you want to show
        if ($contact['type'] === 'CONTACT_TYPE_2') {
            echo '<option value="'.$contact['id'].'">'.$contact['d_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
<select name="contact_type3" class="form-control">
<?php 
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        // fit this code by the `type` you want to show
        if ($contact['type'] === 'CONTACT_TYPE_3') {
            echo '<option value="'.$contact['id'].'">'.$contact['d_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>  
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute query and store data into array... You can use array multiple times..

```
$sql_getContactType1 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_phone_contact_type');

     while($row = $sql_getContactType1->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $row_info[] = $row;
            }


    foreach ($row_info as $info) {
        echo "Id: {$info[id]}<br />"
           . "Name: {$info[name]}<br />"
           . "Code: {$info[code]}<br /><br />";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL for dropdown contact type

```
<?php 
$sql_getContactType1 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_phone_contact_type');

    while($row = $sql_getContactType1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $row_data[] = $row;
    }
?>
```

Output in dropdown :

```
    <select name="contact_type1" class="form-control">
    <?php 
        foreach($row_data as $row_val)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row_val[id].'">'.$row_val[d_name] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>  
    </select>
    <select name="contact_type2" class="form-control">
    <?php 
        foreach($row_data as $row_val)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row_val[id].'">'.$row_val[d_name] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>  
    <select name="contact_type3" class="form-control">
    <?php 
        foreach($row_data as $row_val)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row_val[id].'">'.$row_val[d_name] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>  
     </select>
```

Use above the code if you need 3 dropdown on a page.

Comment: This won't work. The second and third loops won't return anything, because there are no more rows to fetch.